# Using a String to decide which Array to use (c#)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, transform

I wanted to ask if there is a way to transform a String into a arrayname?

**Example:**

I got like 4 arrays:
name,age,gender,nationality

and now i got a String which says "nationality" now i want in my code that i can use that String to access the nationality array. Or if i change the String to "age" i want to access the age array... i hope its clear what i mean.

I dont really know how this could be done and hope you could atleast give me input where to find some informations to this topic.

Hopefully someone can help me!

Greetings from Germany,

Marvin

**edit:**

Thanks for all the answers.. I'm not really well in programming till now so im not sure if i understood everything right.

I guess it doesnt really matter if i do everything with String or have different types in the array because i could convert them or?

I have never worked with Lists till now. And i guess my examople maybe wasnt the best so here is a new one:

I got different array (lets say all String):
I make this Programm for a tabletopgame

```
name              //Name of a hero
points            // Costs for using it
leader            //kinda the fraction
character         //an attribut units got
abilityhelpers    //what does a hero need to be helpfull for this unit
where             //where to serach
```

So i got different units:

```
pete
10
leader a
friendly
less 100 //so every hero that costs less then 100 points helps him
points

mike
110
leader b
smart
leader a //so he is good with heros from leader a
leader
```

The Programm picks random one unit, lets say it picks Mike... no it look what Abilityhelpers he got... and in this case its "leader a" so he should go through all entries in the array Leader and add every hero that got "leader a" to a list.
Then it picks a random one of this list and does the same for him... so if Pete is picked it searches in the array Points for everyone who got less then 100 points.

But i dont want like 1 million if cases for the different posibillities ( there are 8 different attributes and sometimes there are 3 of them as restrictions for a good match (like: leader a, friendly, points less then 5))

I would like to have something like:

String a = where [0]; //a string that contains the information where to search for the helper

```
for(i=0;1<array.length;i++)
{
if (a[i]==abilityhelpers[0])
    //then add name[i] to the list
}
```

I don't want the exact Code for this Problem (and guess i wouldn't get it), i would love to know if that is possible and if yes some advices where to look or some food for my thoughts^^

Comment: If the arrays all contain the same types, you can use `Dictionary<string, List<SomeType>>`, keying the arrays using a string. You can then access like so: `myDictionary["age"]`

Comment: The `System.Array` type already implements several interfaces like IEnumerable, ICollection, and IList. So why not just make it a list or a dictionary like Charleh suggests.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Generic Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) that has key as a string and value as string `array / List<string>`

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dictionary = Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

Or

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dictionary = Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don`t you store the Arrays in a Dictionary. Something like that:

```
Dictionary<string, Array> arrays = new Dictionary<string,Array>();

string key="key";

Array ages = arrays[key];
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your arrays are of ***different types*** (and so you *can't use* `Dictionary<String, T>`) I suggest exploiting `DataTable`:

```
  DataTable table = new DataTable();

  // Age is integer: 34, 81, 19...  
  table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
  // Nationality is String: "English", "Dutch"... 
  table.Columns.Add("Nationality", typeof(String));
  // Gender is Char: 'M' or 'F' 
  table.Columns.Add("Gender", typeof(Char));
  // ...
```

To obtain data form the table:

```
  int[] ages = table
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(row => row["Age"])
    .ToArray();
```